# Paypal Integration with ionic

Tags: paypal, ionic-framework

I have seen people integrated paypal payment with ionic, making payment just needs do a photo taking  of the credit card. I would like to know if there is any SMS sent to the card holder for verification purpose, because the system will be used in offline business, having to key in SMS verification code will be a troublesome thing for customer. Does any friend have done paypal integration for offline business ?